# How to specify document language while importing a dataset in Google Cloud AutoML?

Tags: nlp, google-cloud-ml, multilabel-classification, google-cloud-automl, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am trying to train a model for text classification in VertexAI AutoML (Google Cloud) using documents in Spanish. I imported the documents as JSON lines and tried specifying the language of each document as follows:

```
{"textContent":"Esto está escrito en español","languageCode":"es-ES","classificationAnnotations":[{"displayName":"Class A"},{"displayName":"Class B"}]}
```

According to the [schema file](https://storage.cloud.google.com/google-cloud-aiplatform/schema/dataset/ioformat/text_classification_multi_label_io_format_1.0.0.yaml) in the Vertex AI documentation on [how to prepare the training data](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/datasets/prepare-text#multi-label-classification), the line above should work. However I could not find a way to check whether the language was imported correctly, and if I export the dataset back the `languageCode` field has an empty string as value.

**What is the correct way to specify language of a document while importing it into a dataset? Is there any way to check that the language was imported correctly?**

Comment: This appears to be an unexpected behavior. I'll check further and provide an update afterwards.

Comment: Hi OP, the resolution might take longer than usual. There's no ETA for the fix but engineers are now aware of your concern. You can track the issue publicly on https://issuetracker.google.com/213808331

Comment: As per checking https://issuetracker.google.com/213808331, the issue should now be resolved.